# Applying CSS style to dynamically created DIV

Tags: javascript, css

I successfully created a div dynamically.
But i was wondering is there a way to apply CSS style directly instead of applying style one by one using Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPEy/)**

You should use the `className` property:

`divTag.className = "divdrag";`

The `div` now has the appropriate class name and you just need to add all of your styling to that CSS class.

[**More info here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

Comment: Does not work,i have my .divdrag in css file and Javascript function in other file, do i need to do something else?? Sorry i am newbie

Comment: So you have 3 separate files - 1 CSS, 1 HTML and 1 Javascript? Silly question but did you include a link to the CSS file in your HTML page?

Comment: Yes i have 3 separate files and i have included CSS and Javscript file link in HTML page.

Comment: Did you call the `createDiv` function then? Please check the Demo Fiddle I just added. I changed your CSS a little bit for testing purposes but it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly :) One last question is there anyway to add button or textarea in that dynamically created div??

Comment: Yes, you can use `appendChild` like this: 
`var button = document.createElement("button");
    divTag.appendChild(button);` 
You still need to add styling to the button/textarea of course. More on [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: Sir your genius, thanks a lot for help. It helped me lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `cssText` for apply multiple css to created dynamic div.

```
divTag.style.cssText="align:center; border:1px solid #ccc; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;";
```

**Updated**

Or use simple css based on `div1` id

```
#div1{
    align:center;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

Note you should create the id by

```
divTag.id = "div1";
```

Comment: It works, but still it can get hectic if there are lot of styling needed to be done. Any alternate way?? Thanks

Comment: Then append the paritcular id during the create of div, and write the pure css based on that id, which means the css would be applied only when the id is avaiable.

Comment: please have a look udpated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help it is working now, one small question anyway to add button or texarea in that dynamically created div?? Thanks

Comment: If you want put the `textarea` or `button` into dynamic created div, then you have to append these tags by creating or fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
divTag.classList.add("divdrag");
```

or

```
divTag.className += "divdrag";
```

Answer (score 0):

you set the classes with this..

```
if (divTag.classList) {
  el.classList.add("divdrag");
}
else {
  divTag.className += ' ' + "divdrag";
}
```